# Jstree not recognized in angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, jstree

I am getting the error like below when I try to use jstree inside my application which runs with angularjs. Can anyone tell me whhat would be the issue? I hv added the jquery and jstree source files in dependency on loading of my app.

TypeError: $(...).jstree is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/FirstLife/V6/lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2:2536), :3:30)

Withe the same code, i hv done one example code in plunker and it works just fine. http://embed.plnkr.co/jneh7I48lUnsBiHJZ5oN/

My objective is to display the json data that comes from the server in jstree(and then use the same element to display the org chart)

Comment: I have used the same method in plunker and it works just fine!                              http://embed.plnkr.co/jneh7I48lUnsBiHJZ5oN/

Answer (score 0):

add jstree script before init angularjs

```
<script src="dist/libs/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
```

and check script is loaded